# Entity Framework single object with exception in relations (ObjectDisposeException)

Tags: .net, entity-framework, include

I use EF Database First. When I try get an object from database by using context and don't include some properties I expected that to return null in place of those objects (previously when I used EF in other projects there were nulls). Now I got exceptions on those objects:

Code of getting an object:

```
/// <summary>
/// gets a wallet by id and/or user id
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">Guid</param>
/// <param name="userId">string</param>
/// <returns>FAWallet</returns>
public FAWallet GetWallet(Guid id, string userId = null)
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new FinancialAssistantEntities())
        {
            return context.FAWallet
                .Include(x => x.AspNetUsers)
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.WalletId == id && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId) ? x.AspNetUsers.Id == userId : true));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Error:

[image: Error]

In case of this, I cannot serialize this object and send it back from my API.

Answer (score 0):

You do get null, this is how lazy loading works. But if proxy-generation and lazy-loading are enabled, those null values will be populated when you first reference that property. And when the result object is sent back to the client and it gets serialized, the serialization engine goes through all the properties and that's when lazy-loading kicks in. But by that time you are already out of the using block, so the context is disposed, hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule to avoid issues like this, try to structure your code so that your entities never get passed outside of the scope of your DBContext. The only way to reliably avoid that error with the current structure you are using is to eager-fetch all dependencies which is typically too expensive and not necessary for many situations.

Your error is that you are attempting to consume the FAWallet outside of the DBContext and it's trying to lazy load the FAEntry(ies).  The temporary fix is to add the .Include() around the FAEntry(ies) when you load the FAWallet. Ultimately this will be self-defeating because you're now adding the cost of querying these related entities every time you go to query against FAWallet. (whether they are needed or not)  IMO lazy loading is more of a curse than anything because people easily get trapped with sub-optimal code. They either give up and eager load everything, (expensive) add parameters and attempts to indicate what to eager-fetch, (complex and still error prone) or move the DBContext up so that lazy loading "works" without an error. (slow)

The best solution I can provide is to use a Unit of Work pattern and ensure that data retrieval logic (Repositories and the like) return `IQueryable<TEntity>`. Your consuming code can use whatever Linq operation is suitable, including selecting child entities or custom data structures, as well as perform optimized queries through the use of .Any(), .SingleOrDefault(), .FirstOrDefault(), .Take(), etc.  These are done at a level just before you want to pass the data to your presentation layer, to compose view models.  If your code returns IQueryable your consuming code does something like:

```
using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork()) // Insert whichever unit of work pattern...
{
  var wallets = WalletRepository.GetWalletById(unitOfWork, walletId, userId);
  var viewModel = wallets.Select(w=> new { w.WalletId, w.WalletName, Entries = w.FAEntries.Select(e=> new {e.EntryId, e.EntryAmount}) }).SingleOrDefault();
  return viewModel;
}
```

The GetWalletById returns `IQuerable<FAWallet>` rather than an FAWallet. The reason for this is that it gives me the flexibility to control how this result is consumed. The next line in this case lets me further compose the query that EF will eventually run to only retrieve the details I care about for the view model. If I'd used a method that return an FAWallet I'd either have to explicitly eager fetch related entities and then return everything from the database even though I don't need it, or I'd end up with lazy loading calls to the DB. The `IQueryable<FAWallet>` also gives me flexibility. I can use the same method with a .Any() to check if a row exists, use different .Select() expressions to serve other areas of the application, support pagination with Take() and Skip(), etc.

Have a look at the Unit of Work pattern. There are several implementations and examples on how to use it. The pattern I promote for EF is Mehdime's DbContext Scope. The idea is to wrap the DbContext and have the outer-most layers that interact with your domain establish the unit of work, while the services etc. that deal with the business logic and data retrieval get passed the unit of work to access the DbContext.  Anything travelling to/from views would be converted to/from View Models rather than relying on Entities. The benefits of this is ensuring you aren't pulling more data than you need (faster) and it's a lot less issue-prone than dealing with detached / reattached entities.